# Moving symbols around a table with user inputs

Tags: python, input

I am creating a simple text based game set on a 20x30 grid where the user should be able to move the character around (represented by a symbol) the game world (which is created by a table). I am just wonder how do I go about getting my character symbol to move from one column to another, or from one row to another. The user cannot get the character to move diagonally so no need to worry about that.

So for an example, if the user enters 8, then the symbol should move one row.

I don't have any code written out for this function yet because I don't really know where to begin. Just looking for some pointers to start me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of programming! My first program also was a text based console game. (Hangman written in Java)

I'd suggest you the following.

Save the coordinates of the character. When your user gives some input change the corresponding coordinate.

On startup and after each move print your table everytime completely new (refreshing the existing one is not trivial but once you're more experienced you might want to use [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)).
Keep in mind that you have to print the table row by row (just as you are reading). Once you printed something you cannot go back!

Functions you will need are `input` (`raw_input` if using python2.x), `print` and `range`.

Just two hints
If you want to print some text e.g. 10 times you can write `print('text'*10)` of course `10` and `'text'` can be variables!

If you want to print a single character you need `print('a',end='')` if using python2.7 you have to put `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of your script for this to work.

I also find the api references ([python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html) [python3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/py-modindex.html)) very helpful, keep them bookmarked in your browser ;)

Happy coding!